# How to programmatically cancel .Net webforms ListView edit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms

I have a .Net WebForms application that uses a ListView and the built in edit capabilities. The page contains the ability to select the ListView data based on a dropdown.

Currently when I change the data the row number that was being edited before changing the data, continues to use the EditItemTemplate with the new data.

What I want to do is change the data from this dropdown and cancel any existing edits from the dropdown's change event, but I'm not seeing how to get the row that is being edited out of EditItemTemplate and back to the standard ItemTemplate.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If I'm going in the wrong direction, please let me know. I see people have started to down vote this. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! `ListView.EditIndex = -1`